# Java - Optional loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, do-while

This is my code:

```
/* Linear equation student quiz
 * This program creates equations of the form ax + b = c for students to solve.
 */

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathFunction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b, c;

        double userAnswer, correctAnswer;
        int numCorrect = 0;
        Random ranNum = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int problem = 1; problem <= 10; problem++)
        {
            a = ranNum.nextInt(2) + 1;
            b = ranNum.nextInt(41) - 20;
            c = ranNum.nextInt(41) - 20;

            System.out.print("\n"+ a + "x + " + b + " = " + c + " ... x = ");

            userAnswer = input.nextDouble();
            correctAnswer = 1.0 * (c - b) / a;

            if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
            {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                numCorrect =+ 1;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, correct answer is " + correctAnswer);
            }

        }//end for loop
        System.out.println("You got " + numCorrect + " out of ten.");
        System.out.println("\nWant to do 10 more questions? <y/n>");

    }//end main
}//end class
```

I want to be able to return to the loop if the user enters the character 'y'. The user will be prompted of this option every time they complete 10 of the math problems. Would I use a 'do-while'?

Comment: Wrap your process in a while loop

Comment: why is all your text bold?

Comment: I would suggest you break you coding in methods or functions so that it would be easy for you to call a method if a user input is Y and close a program if user input is N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what I mean by breaking your program into methods,

/* Linear equation student quiz
 * This program creates equations of the form ax + b = c for students to solve.
 */

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathFunction {

    int a, b, c;
    double userAnswer, correctAnswer;
    int numCorrect = 0; 
    Random ranNum = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //You function to calculate
    public static compute()
    {
     for (int problem = 1; problem <= 10; problem++)
        {
            a = ranNum.nextInt(2) + 1;
            b = ranNum.nextInt(41) - 20;
            c = ranNum.nextInt(41) - 20;

            System.out.print("\n"+ a + "x + " + b + " = " + c + " ... x = ");

            userAnswer = input.nextDouble();
            correctAnswer = 1.0 * (c - b) / a;

            if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
            {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                numCorrect =+ 1;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, correct answer is " + correctAnswer);
            }

        }//end for loop
         System.out.println("You got " + numCorrect + " out of ten.");
         System.out.println("\nWant to do 10 more questions? <y/n>");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Then start by sking a question like "Ready to staxt Y/N"

        //get user responce or user input and if user input is Y then call the compute method else  system exit.

        if(userAnswer=="Y")
        {
            compute();
        }
        else{
            //Thanks for participating system closes.
            System.exit(0);
        }



    }//end main
}//end class
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should wrap the for loop with a do-while loop that checks if the user entered 'y'.

```
do {
    for (...) {
        ...
    }
    System.out.println("You got " + numCorrect + " out of ten.");
    System.out.println("\nWant to do 10 more questions? <y/n>");
    input.nextLine();
    String repeat = input.nextLine();
} while (repeat.equals("y"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution

```
String choice = "y";
while(choice.equals("y")){
for (int problem = 1; problem <= 10; problem++)
    {
        a = ranNum.nextInt(2) + 1;
        b = ranNum.nextInt(41) - 20;
        c = ranNum.nextInt(41) - 20;



System.out.print("\n"+ a + "x + " + b + " = " + c + " ... x = ");

    userAnswer = input.nextDouble();
    correctAnswer = 1.0 * (c - b) / a;

    if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
    {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        numCorrect =+ 1;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, correct answer is " + correctAnswer);
    }

}//end for loop
System.out.println("You got " + numCorrect + " out of ten.");
System.out.println("\nWant to do 10 more questions? <y/n>");
choice = input.nextLine(); // get the input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-> Wrap your code in a do while loop.

-> Also use `input.nextLine()` for reading all user inputs (double value and string "y" or "n"), as switching between `input.nextDouble()` and `input.nextLine()` , can sometimes cause errors. Parse the input value to `double` after user input.

```
 outer: //label
 do{
 for (int problem = 1; problem <= 10; problem++)
{
    a = ranNum.nextInt(2) + 1;
    b = ranNum.nextInt(41) - 20;
    c = ranNum.nextInt(41) - 20;

    System.out.print("\n"+ a + "x + " + b + " = " + c + " ... x = ");

    try{
    userAnswer = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine()); //use this to get double input from user
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
   //warn user of wrong input 
    break outer;
    }

    correctAnswer = 1.0 * (c - b) / a;

    if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
    {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        numCorrect =+ 1;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, correct answer is " + correctAnswer);
    }

}//end for loop
System.out.println("You got " + numCorrect + " out of ten.");
System.out.println("\nWant to do 10 more questions? <y/n>");

if(input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
continue outer; //if user wants to continue
 }
else{
break outer; //if user does not want to continue, break out of outer do-while loop
}

}
while(true);
```